# how do choose the two select sum at the same time

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use that formula

like this

```
sum((freight/sum(Quantity))*Quantity) for lineitemfright
```

that code I tried was not summing the one value that I want

```
select sum(
     (
        Northwind.dbo.orders.Freight 
        /
        (
            select SUM(
                Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].Quantity
            )
            from Northwind.dbo.[Order Details] 
            where Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = Northwind.dbo.orders.OrderID
        )
        *
        Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].Quantity
    )
) as LineItemFreight 
from Northwind.dbo.[Order Details] 
inner join Northwind.dbo.Orders 
on Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].OrderID= northwind.dbo.Orders.OrderID
where Northwind.dbo.orders.ShippedDate is not null
```

however it kept getting an error saying.

```
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
 sum((freight/sum(Quantity))*Quantity)
```

I am trying to sum in one value without using grouping by.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using the database called Northwind.

Comment: when I took one sum out I get multiple numbers  and all I want to do is to have one number. select (Northwind.dbo.orders.Freight/ 
  (select SUM(Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].Quantity)
  from Northwind.dbo.[Order Details]
  where  Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].OrderID
   =Northwind.dbo.orders.OrderID )
   *Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].Quantity) as LineItemFreight
  from Northwind.dbo.[Order Details]
inner join Northwind.dbo.Orders on  Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].OrderID=
northwind.dbo.Orders.OrderID
where Northwind.dbo.orders.ShippedDate is not null

Comment: I meant which database *vendor* (mysql, sqlserver, oracle, postgres, etc). The solution may depend on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

use a variable and do it

```
  @DECLARE @tEMPSUM bigint

    SET @TEMPSUM=select SUM(Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].Quantity)from Northwind.dbo.[Order Details] 
            where Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = Northwind.dbo.orders.OrderID
```

then

```
select sum((Northwind.dbo.orders.Freight / @tEMPSUM)*Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].Quantity) as LineItemFreight 
from Northwind.dbo.[Order Details] 
inner join Northwind.dbo.Orders 
on Northwind.dbo.[Order Details].OrderID= northwind.dbo.Orders.OrderID
where Northwind.dbo.orders.ShippedDate is not null
```